# How to align right a TextView in RelativeLayout which layout_width is wrap_content and it's parent layout has wrap_content to

Tags: android

I want to make a simple chat layout with the hour of every message aligned bottom right of text (like in Whatsapp).  The width of every message changes dynamically so I have to set the layout_width to wrap_content.  In this case gravity or **layout_gravity** doesn't affect the hour but I don't know how to make it different. Here is the code. *txtMessage* is the message and *ora* is the hour that I want to align bottom right **under** the message. 
Thank you

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentWithBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/risponditore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="@color/bluScuro"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
            android:layout_below="@+id/risponditore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:maxWidth="245dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/contenitoreOra"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="right">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ora"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textColor="@color/grigioScuro"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDITED:

I want to have this kind of layout:

```
Text message Text message Text message Text message
Text message Text message Text message Text message
Text message Text message Text message Text message
                                               hour
```

Comment: add this line android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

Comment: What about `android:layout_toRightOf`

Comment: Sorry for my english, what I want is have the hour in the bottom right corner of the message

Comment: alignParentRight works but streches the width of the message to the whole screen width and that is what I don't want. layout_toRightOf makes the hour to stay right of the message and I don't want this neither

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I obtained a solution using TableLayout with two rows.
The first row contain the message and the second row contain the hour.
The message is aligned left and the hour right.
Below is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentWithBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/risponditore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="@color/bluScuro"/>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabellaMessaggioOra"
            android:layout_below="@+id/risponditore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/rigaMessaggio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:maxWidth="245dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/rigaOra"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ora"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/grigioScuro"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"/>

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Glad to see you solved your problem. I tried. Move ahead .

Comment: Thank you aniway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[android:layout_toRightOf](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_toRightOf)** **Logic** .

> Positions the left edge of this view to the right of the given anchor
>   view ID. Accommodates left margin of this view and right margin of
>   anchor view.

**Example**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Intellij"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Amiyo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnButton1"/>
```

**FYQ**

Use **`android:gravity="bottom|right"`**

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/ora"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:text="Text message"
                android:gravity="bottom|right"/>
```

Comment: yes, this works but I was not correct in the question, you can see the edited part of the question. I want the hour to stay under the message in the right corner. thank you

Comment: @IvaPesa done . set `android:gravity="bottom|right"` instead of `android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"`

Comment: Thank you IntelliJ Amiya but I've already tried to use android:gravity but it doesn't work. It seems that gravity and layout_gravity work only if you set the parent layout's width to specific number or to match_parent. But if it's wrap_content it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use LinearLayout in this case, it will work if you give gravity in LinearLayout. Ignore this if you want RelativeLayout strictly.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contenitoreOra"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="right">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ora"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textColor="@color/grigioScuro"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```